# Minecraft Retractable staircase hangs on one side - sticky piston

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've build a retractable staircase. But, on the right side, the sticky piston stays in the open position. Does anyone know why?

[image]

[image]

[image: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/193/20120106103704.png/]

Comment: Without seeing the mechanism you've created it's going to be difficult to suggest why it's not working. A short video showing what you've built and the problem might go a long way here.

Comment: A couple of screenshots will be fine too.

Comment: A possible problem may be that redstone current only travels through 15 blocks of wire. It's impossible to tell without seeing what you're doing though.

Comment: Redstone is working and powered. I've uploaded a few screenshots.

Comment: We'll need pictures on the redstone on the right side to find the source of the problem...

Comment: To control for every factor, please tell us which direction the staircase is facing.

Answer (score 5):

I've made a demo replica of your construction, in all possible orientations:

I can't imagine what can be wrong in such trivial design. Do you have the latest Minecraft? Any mods installed? Any redstone wiring/torches underneath the staircase?

**UPD** Changed the video, the old one is [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uQfWMd4buFE).

Comment: I notice that yours is an extra block wide; that might make the difference if this is one of the "piston quasiconnectivity" glitches.

Comment: There is no difference, just tested, isn't worth a video.

Comment: you also might want to test if the directionality of the stairs matter.

Comment: I've updated my video.

Comment: +1 for research. I notice one difference though: the original design has a layer of stone blocks above the pistons and the retracted stairs, so maybe that causes trouble. Or maybe the positioning of the switch at the bottom of the stairs is relevant as well?

Comment: I think these stone blocks shouldn't affect behavior of pistons, because repeaters transfer power to the block in front of it and to one below the first block.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be the victim of the piston update bug. when large contraptions update the pistons do not seem to respond. (if you look up Captiansparkles on youtube he runs into the same problem in one video) try building the same contraption in another place and see if it works or a different set of pistons refuse to update.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when large amounts of pistons are being used, some will not update.